# 4 Divs and a menu bar (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a split in 4 screen layout for a website.
I thought I'd just set 4 `divs`, `50%` of `height and width`, `float left and right`.

But I need to add a menu bar in the middle of all this.
I did it by adding a div after the first 2 divs, and set the menu bar `div` "`clear`" `css` tag to "`both`".

I'm almost there...the thing is that there's this scroll bar appearing since now, it's 50% + menu bar height + another 50%...

I just need to find a way to make the menu bar fit in this...without having a scroll bar on the right when the window is smaller. (I was using overflow : hidden at first, but people with small screens will not see the drop down items from the menu).

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttCJG/) (that's a simple way to show my issue)

Any idea? Thank you!

**EDIT :**

Look what it does when you resize the window, and scroll with images : http://jsfiddle.net/ttCJG/2/

Comment: You could set the height of the divs to around 45% and then the menu bar to 10%. But you probably don't want a variable height menu, but you may have to deal with that if you really don't want a scrollbar. Or you could use javascript to tell you the dimensions of the screen and set the heights of your elements.

Comment: That's what I thought. Maybe someone has an idea? Thanks for your comment watson

Comment: What @watson has suggested is the easiest way around else you will have to write a function to calculate the respective width & height  using page width & height and assign them to the 4 divs and menu div. If you need the function to calculate width and height, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/ttCJG/1/

```css
#menu-bar {
    height:30px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:black;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
    clear:both;
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
}​
```

Comment: Well it's working correctly. Except that what I forgot to add is images. Look what it does : http://jsfiddle.net/ttCJG/2/ ...Make the window smaller, and then scroll down. The container divs will stop there, and once you scroll, the image will continu but no color from the container div

Comment: this happens because of `height:100%;` on your `body` - it sets the height to 100% of visible window

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height for the menu bar from the top and bottom `<div>`s

**Example**:
Top Divs: 40%
Menu: 20%
Bottom Divs: 40%

They might need to be tweaked but that's it in a nutshell. Try something like this CSS:

```css
html, body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;   
}
#test1 {
 width:50%;
 height:47%;
 float:left;
 background-color:red;       
}
#test2 {
 width:50%;
 height:47%;
 float:right;
 background-color:blue;       
}
#test3 {
 width:50%;
 height:47%;
 float:left;
 background-color:green;       
}
#test4 {
 width:50%;
 height:47%;
 float:right;
 background-color:yellow;       
}
#menu-bar {
 height:6%;
 width:100%;
 background-color:black;
 margin:0;
 clear:both;
 color:white;
}​
```